# Where the actual db fetch is done in drf list()

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

As you may know the querysets do the actual fetch data only when you evaluate them for ex iterating over them. I want to put that actual fetch inside celery so I need to catch the method in which that actual fetch data from db happens during drf lifecycle. what is it?

I'm diving in drf source code but since I have not much time any help is appreciated.

Comment: Given you do this in celery, how will you communicate the data back? If that is done through a file, or the celery stream, it will take aproximately the same bandwidth.

Comment: What the exact problem you are trying to solve? This sounds like workaround for different issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the serializer**. Indeed, if you construct a `MySerializer(many=True)`, it will wrap your `MySerializer` in a `ListSerializer` which uses `MySerializer` as child.

In the [**`.to_representation(…)`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a45432b54de88b28bd2e6db31acfe3dbcfc748dd/rest_framework/serializers.py#L717-L727), it then will enumerate the `data` and call the subserializer of each item:

> ```
> def to_representation(self, data):
>     '\n    List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.\n'
>     # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
>     # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
>     iterable = (
>         data.all() if isinstance(data, models.manager.BaseManager) else data
>     )
>
>     return [self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable]
> ```

So it enumerates over the queryset in this scenario, and then it will let the `.child` serialize each item individually.

> I want to put that actual fetch inside celery so I need to catch the method in which that actual fetch data from db happens during drf lifecycle.

Given you do that, it will likely generate a blob of equal size that is serialized, and therefore communicating the result from celery back to the Django backend will become the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand the bottleneck you pointed to, celery stores the results in redis and I get them using django, what is problem??

Comment: @Ellnamin: that the amount of data will be comparable to the data from the database. So moving the fetch to celery that will then put it on redis, will not boost performance, but will likely only make it worse.